# consulta en mongodb devuelve documento incompleto

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

estoy haciendo una consult a mongo db mediante mongoose, estoy usando el metodo `populate` para traer documentos que estan apuntando a otra coleccion, la sigueinte consulta:

```
Usuario.findById(posteo.autor, {notificaciones: 1, socket: 1})
   .populate({path: 'notificaciones'})
    .exec((err, result: any)=>{
         result.notificaciones.addToSet(ex._id)
         console.log(result)
         if(err) return false
         return this.io.to(result.socket).emit('newNoti', result.notificaciones)
 })
```

me tiene que devolver un array con los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a mi parecer, esto esta bien, pero no entiendo por que el objeto que me devuelve la consulta no me lo devuelve completo, faltan algunos datos, la consulta me devuelve esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El array `de` no tiene el objet id que tiene que tenes, y me falta el campo `tipo` que tampoco me esta mostrando, no entiendo por que si en mongodb compas se guardo correctamente el documento, tendria que haberlo devuelto completo, gracias por su atencion.

Comment: ¿Existe la referencia adecuada en el esquema de esa colección? ¿Cómo actualizas los datos del campo tipo `Array` llamado `de`?. ¿A qué colección hace referencia el objeto (o los objetos) almacenados en el campo `de`?

Comment: mira que este en el schema todo lo que pides

Comment: te refieres a mi modelo?